# Work around an issue or workaround an issue?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I'm writing an essay for college admissions, and this snippet is highlighted by my auto-correct as incorrect:

> There are many obstacles I face while working on a project, most of which take a lot of time and energy to fix or ***work around***.

I can't see anything wrong with using *work around* in this context, but I'd like to know how to correctly use this phrase.

Comment: Your intuition is correct, and your auto-correct is auto-wrong. This has been covered before for *login* vs. *log in*, *backup* vs. *back up*, *fallback* vs. *fall back*, *payoff* and *pay off*, and so on and so forth. The answer is always exactly the same, noun vs. verb, but your auto-correct simply failed to pick up that this is a verb (if it is capable of distinguishing between parts of speech at all).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[*Work around*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+around) is a phrasal verb. [*Work-around*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/work-around) is a noun (often written *workaround,* without the hyphen). Your example uses the verb, so it is correct as written. Ignore the auto-correct suggestion in this case.

Comment: Isn't that GR :)

Comment: Yeah, but the OP didn't know which reference to believe.